# Access Denied when access another site collection properties

Tags: 2013, site-collection, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have two site collections:

1. `http://company` - this is main portal
2. `http://company:200` - this is personal sites.

On a personal sites collection, in its root web properties we stores `Guid` of main portal site collection: `personalWeb.Properties[MainPortalGuid]`.

On a main site, also in `web.Properties` we had stored some specific info: `mainWeb.Properties[SomeInfo]`

Being in Personal sites collection, I need to access this specific info, and I always get **"Access denied"** exception when trying to read main site properties. I'm acting that way:

```
Guid portalGuid = new Guid();
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
string pesonalSitesUrl = upm.MySiteHostUrl;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite personalSite = new SPSite(pesonalSitesUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb personalWeb = personalSite.RootWeb)
        {
            string guid = personalWeb.Properties[MainPortalGuid];
            portalGuid = new Guid(guid);
        }
    }

    using (SPSite secureSite = new SPSite(portalGuid))
    {
        using (SPWeb secureWeb = secureSite.RootWeb))
        {
            // And this line throws "access denied" exception:
            if (secureWeb.Properties.ContainsKey(CommonConsts.RssKeyCommon))
            {
                someInfo = secureWeb.Properties[SomeInfo];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I'm creating new `SPSite/SPWeb objects` in `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` delegate. All Guids and consts are correct, all properties exists and not empty.

I've also tried `SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException` with no luck.

Comment: Does that Personal Site belong to you or someone else?

Comment: Personal Site and Main Portal  are in the same farm, on the same virtual server. Or  maybe you means something else by "belongs to me"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found the answer - the problem is that these site collections were created under different Application Pool Users. 
Main portal runs under `Pool_Portal_User`, and Personal Sites  runs under `Pool_Personal_User`.

Because of that we've got **Access Denied** when trying to access Main Portal from Personal Sites.

To resolve this, we need to grant access to `Pool_Personal_User` on Main Portal.

In SharePoint PowerShell console (run as Fram administrator account):

```
$app = Get-SPWebApplication http://company
$app.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("Domain\Pool_Personal_User")
$app.Update()
```